# Access this in jquery each function

Tags: jquery

How can I acces my object variables within a $.each function?

```
function MyClass()
{
  this.mySetting = 'Hallo';
  this.arr = [{caption: 'Bla', type: 'int'}, {caption: 'Blurr', type: 'float'}];
}

MyClass.prototype.doSomething = function() {

  $.each(this.arr, function() {
    //this here is an element of arr.
    //...but how can I access mySetting??
  });
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Store `this` in a variable, e.g. called `that` or `self`:

```
MyClass.prototype.doSomething = function() {
  var self = this;
  $.each(this.arr, function(idx, elem) {
    // use self here - and do not use this to access the element but elem
  });
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it! :) (I prefer `that`, because `self` feels more like a language keyword)

Comment: so there is no option to do something like $.each(this.arr, function(myobjectvar) { myobjectvar.mySetting
  })(this); ?

Comment: It does not have a `context` argument, so you cannot make it set `this` to something else.